# How do I set the Tag of joints[] to what I want in this script?

Tags: unity, c#, rope-physics, joints

Hello I got this big script for building a Rope from position a to position b.
The joints are getting instantiated but the tag is default, what I have to change in the script to set the Tag of the joints ?

"I didnt wrote this script!"

Here is the RopeScript:

```
public class RopeScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float resolution = 0.5F;                           //  Sets the amount of joints there are in the rope (1 = 1 joint for every 1 unit)
public float ropeDrag = 0.1F;                                //  Sets each joints Drag
public float ropeMass = 0.1F;                           //  Sets each joints Mass
public float ropeColRadius = 0.5F;                  //  Sets the radius of the collider in the SphereCollider component
//public float ropeBreakForce = 25.0F;                   //-------------- TODO (Hopefully will break the rope in half...
private Vector3[] segmentPos;           //  DONT MESS!  This is for the Line Renderer's Reference and to set up the positions of the gameObjects
private GameObject[] joints;            //  DONT MESS!  This is the actual joint objects that will be automatically created
private LineRenderer line;                          //  DONT MESS!   The line renderer variable is set up when its assigned as a new component
private int segments = 0;                   //  DONT MESS!  The number of segments is calculated based off of your distance * resolution
private bool rope = false;                       //  DONT MESS! This is to keep errors out of your debug window! Keeps the rope from rendering when it doesnt exist...

//Joint Settings
public Vector3 swingAxis = new Vector3(1,1,1);               //  Sets which axis the character joint will swing on (1 axis is best for 2D, 2-3 axis is best for 3D (Default= 3 axis))
public float lowTwistLimit = -100.0F;                   //  The lower limit around the primary axis of the character joint. 
public float highTwistLimit = 100.0F;                   //  The upper limit around the primary axis of the character joint.
public float swing1Limit  = 20.0F;                  //  The limit around the primary axis of the character joint starting at the initialization point.

void Awake()
{
    BuildRope();
}

void Update()
{
    // Put rope control here!


    //Destroy Rope Test (Example of how you can use the rope dynamically)
    if(rope && Input.GetKeyDown("p"))
    {
        DestroyRope();  
    }   
    if(!rope && Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
    {
        BuildRope();
    }
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    // Does rope exist? If so, update its position
    if(rope) {
        for(int i=0;i<segments;i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                line.SetPosition(i,transform.position);
            } else
            if(i == segments-1) {
                line.SetPosition(i,target.transform.position);  
            } else {
                line.SetPosition(i,joints[i].transform.position);
            }
        }
        line.enabled = true;
    } else {
        line.enabled = false;   
    }
}



void BuildRope()
{
    line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    // Find the amount of segments based on the distance and resolution
    // Example: [resolution of 1.0 = 1 joint per unit of distance]
    segments = (int)(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position)*resolution);
    line.SetVertexCount(segments);
    segmentPos = new Vector3[segments];
    joints = new GameObject[segments];
    segmentPos[0] = transform.position;
    segmentPos[segments-1] = target.position;

    // Find the distance between each segment
    var segs = segments-1;
    var seperation = ((target.position - transform.position)/segs);

    for(int s=1;s < segments;s++)
    {
        // Find the each segments position using the slope from above
        Vector3 vector = (seperation*s) + transform.position;   
        segmentPos[s] = vector;

        //Add Physics to the segments
        AddJointPhysics(s);
    }

    // Attach the joints to the target object and parent it to this object  
    CharacterJoint end = target.gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterJoint>();
    end.connectedBody = joints[joints.Length-1].transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    end.swingAxis = swingAxis;
    SoftJointLimit limit_setter = end.lowTwistLimit;
    limit_setter.limit = lowTwistLimit;
    end.lowTwistLimit = limit_setter;
    limit_setter = end.highTwistLimit;
    limit_setter.limit = highTwistLimit;
    end.highTwistLimit = limit_setter;
    limit_setter = end.swing1Limit;
    limit_setter.limit = swing1Limit;
    end.swing1Limit = limit_setter;
    target.parent = transform;

    // Rope = true, The rope now exists in the scene!
    rope = true;
}

void AddJointPhysics(int n)
{
    joints[n] = new GameObject("Joint_" + n);
    joints[n].transform.parent = transform;
    Rigidbody rigid = joints[n].AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    SphereCollider col = joints[n].AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
    CharacterJoint ph = joints[n].AddComponent<CharacterJoint>();
    ph.swingAxis = swingAxis;
    SoftJointLimit limit_setter = ph.lowTwistLimit;
    limit_setter.limit = lowTwistLimit;
    ph.lowTwistLimit = limit_setter;
    limit_setter = ph.highTwistLimit;
    limit_setter.limit = highTwistLimit;
    ph.highTwistLimit = limit_setter;
    limit_setter = ph.swing1Limit;
    limit_setter.limit = swing1Limit;
    ph.swing1Limit = limit_setter;
    //ph.breakForce = ropeBreakForce; <--------------- TODO

    joints[n].transform.position = segmentPos[n];

    rigid.drag = ropeDrag;
    rigid.mass = ropeMass;
    col.radius = ropeColRadius;

    if(n==1){       
        ph.connectedBody = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    } else
    {
        ph.connectedBody = joints[n-1].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();   
    }

}

void DestroyRope()
{
    // Stop Rendering Rope then Destroy all of its components
    rope = false;
    for(int dj=0;dj<joints.Length-1;dj++)
    {
        Destroy(joints[dj]);    
    }

    segmentPos = new Vector3[0];
    joints = new GameObject[0];
    segments = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit question titles to include things like "SOLVED," the site already displays that information to users because you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you instantiate each joint in `AddJointPhysics`, here:

```
joints[n] = new GameObject("Joint_" + n);
```

At this point, `joints[n]` contains the new joint game object, and you should just be able to do `joints[n].tag = ...` to assign whatever you want (in place of `...`) to the object's tag property.

Comment: Ah, thank you I was trying joints[].tag = "..."; but I did forgor the n in the [ ]
and I didnt wrote the script, I found it in the internet for creating ropes.
But your comment helped me, thanks :)